# when I am trying to perform an operation on open web site I am getting null pointer exception

Tags: selenium

Hello everyone I have created one  utility package under that I have created one below class

```
utility package    

public class Utils           
{
    public static  void  openBrowser(WebDriver driver,String url)            
    {            
        System.out.println("Internet Explorer is selected");         

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\Requirede for Automation\\IEDriverServer.exe");          
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();            
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);       
        driver.manage().window().maximize();           
        driver.get(url);      
    }      
}
```

now the above class I am trying to access in my main automation package  and able to do so but when I am trying to perform an operation on open web site I am getting null pointer exception so can some please tell me what is the correct way to call a class and do the operation on it.

```
public class dropdown 
{           

    WebDriver driver;                

    @Test       
    public void openBrowser() {        

        String url = ("https://loadfocus.com/blog/2016/06/13/how-to-select-adropdown-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java");                                            

        WebDriver driver = null;                                   
        utility.Utils.openBrowser(driver, url);                                                
    }                         

    @Test                                      

    public void open()  
    {                                                 

        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mySelect")));                                          
        dropdown.selectByIndex(2);                                                        
    }                                                  
}
```

error received below

> Internet Explorer is selected Started InternetExplorerDriver server
>   (32-bit)
>   2.39.0.0 Listening on port 18171 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Aug 30, 2017 1:54:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS PASSED: openBrowser FAILED:
>   open java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   automationFramework.dropdown.open(dropdown.java:45)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a `NullPointerException` because when you are invoking `openBrowser()` method you are sending the `driver` as `null` because you have kept `WebDriver driver = null`.

The solution to your question would be to initialize the `WebDriver` instance and cast it to `InternetExplorerDriver` in your test class i.e. `dropdown` class.

The changes you require are:

- class `dropdown`:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); //add the cast                                  
  utility.Utils.openBrowser(driver, url);
  ```
- class `Utils`:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\Requirede for Automation\\IEDriverServer.exe");          
  // remove "driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();"            
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the ans but this is also not working for me because  i am able to open web site whatever code i have written. but after that i am not able to perform any operation on that web site

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you really want to do based on your code snipped is have your openBrowser() method be a setup method. Currently you have a local instance of driver initialized by the openBrowser method which the open() method does not use hence NPE. Try the following

```
@Before
public void openBrowser() {
    String url = ("https://loadfocus.com/blog/2016/06/13/how-to-select-adropdown-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java");                                            

    driver = utility.Utils.openBrowser(driver, url); 
}

@Test
public void open() {
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mySelect")));                                          
    dropdown.selectByIndex(2);   
}
```

This would also require that you openBrowser() in your Utils class returns the instance of the browser. I would actually consider having a static method in your Utils class that simply initializes the driver and returns the instance but that's all in how you want to design your classes.

Also keep in mind @Before executes before every test, perhaps you may want to use @BeforeMethod or @BeforeClass depending on what your goals. It also depends on whether you're using TestNG or JUnit but the documentation for both is worth looking at.

Answer (score -1):

Add IEDriverServer.exe in

> C:\Windows\System32

and restart your machine.  it'll run successfully.